# TypeScript: function that returns a generic Type which extends Record<string, string>

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to create a `parse<Type>()` function that parses a string and returns an object, but I want `parse()` to return the correct type, and I am struggling.

```
type Identity = {
  name: string;
};

type ContactDetails = {
  phone: string;
  email: string;
};

function parse<T extends Record<string, string>>(input: string): T {
  const result = {};
  input.split('&').forEach(bits => {
    const [name, value] = bits.split('=');
    result[name] = value;
  });
  return result;
}

parse<Identity>('name=Paulin');
parse<ContactDetails>('phone=0123456789&email=paulin@email.com');
```

I get a TypeScript error:

> Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>     '{}' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Record'.ts(2322)

I understand what the problem is: `{}` is not compatible with a generic `Record` type. But how can I solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `return result as any;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is one of the places you have to resort to a type assertion. In this case:

```
function parse<T extends Record<string, string>>(input: string): T {
  const result: Record<string, string> = {};
// −−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  input.split('&').forEach(bits => {
    const [name, value] = bits.split('=');
    result[name] = value;
  });
  return result as T;
// −−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
}
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=10&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJhAdsAlqKBeKBvAUFKRAQwFsIAuKAZ2ACcVEBzAblwF9XdRIoBhAe2REAxsAAiEYERQAbKphz4oYABaCK1OgxZKIJaTMo16TVh1y4AZgFdEolIOVFaVCAB4AKlAgAPYEjh5ACUIYX5aODdjbQAaTRNGAD5EgAoGMGtgIy0mAEpKLzwCMMQaKFoIKmsZLKgQsIionMY46KZEhWxzAnTMgDoqMBk0FIByADJR3L7LcIBRERUUgCM0eQwOooIoErKAbWIyOIA3IhlrCABdBVXgKgGhkdGMKdZt8srq4APSK4VT84QN5QNi5YEVYDWWiID5VGpQIjyDxmCxgZyuNzwJCoUCpUaHCAYAAKRGqDFeuDRLncAiEogkUlkVDxqnUGAADABGABMAGYACwAVgAbAB2AAcAE5xnoDBg0WTEAABWWyPphEivIA)

It's important to understand the limitations here, though. If your `Identity` or `ContactDetails` types had specific implementations (they don't in your example, they're just `interface`s), the object `parse` returns won't be backed by that implementation. It **is** just a `Record<string, string>`. So you might be better off having `parse` return a `Record<string, string>` instead, and leave it to the caller to make an informed decision about the type.

Comment: I wanted the caller to make the decision as you said, that's why I wanted to use <T>. But I understand that it is better in this case to use `as`, as so: 
`const identity = parse('name=Paulin') as Identity;`

Comment: @PaulinTrognon - I *think* it is, but I'm still only so far along in my TypeScript education. Your other option is the above with `const identity = parse<Identity>('name=Paulin');` In both cases, the caller is explicitly doing it, which to me is the important thing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what T.J. Crowder suggested: leave it to the caller to make the decision about the type.
here is my final implementation:

```
type Identity = {
  name: string;
};

type ContactDetails = {
  phone: string;
  email: string;
};

function parse(input: string): Record<string, string> {
  const result: Record<string, string> = {};
  input.split('&').forEach(bits => {
    const [name, value] = bits.split('=');
    result[name] = value;
  });
  return result;
}

const identity = parse('name=Paulin') as Identity;
const details = parse('phone=0123456789&email=paulin@email.com') as ContactDetails;
```